# How to increase disk size when building yocto

Tags: yocto

The default yocto image is about 1GB after bitbake core-image-minimal.

The free space is couple hundred MB.

How to assign or increase it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you want to add 8G extra then you can set following in `local.conf`

```
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE_append = " + 8000000"
```

Another way to do is to set `IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR` which will increase the size of image proportionally to the size of the content of image e.g.

```
 IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR = "1.5"
```

will multiply the original size with 1.5 to create the final image.

also read through [documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#idm46227305761344) for details.